# bash loop file echo to each file in the directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I searched a while and tried it by myself but unable to get this sorted so far. My folder looks below, 4 files

```
1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt, 5.txt, 6.txt
```

I want to print file modified time and `echo` the time stamp in it

```
#!/bin/bash
thedate= `ls | xargs stat -s | grep -o "st_mtime=[0-9]*" | sed "s/st_mtime=//g"`   #get file modified time
files= $(ls | grep -Ev '(5.txt|6.txt)$') #exclud 5 and 6 text file

for i in $thedate; do
    echo $i >>  $files  
done
```

I want to insert each timestamp to each file. but having "ambiguous redirect" error. am I doing it incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: You can not redirect to several files. You need a loop to select each file to update.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a `forEach` method ?

Comment: Yes, `for file in $files; do ... ; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `files` is a "list" of files, so you probably want to add another loop to handle them one by one.

Your description is slightly confusing but, if your intent is to append the last modification date of *each* file to that file, you can do something like:

```
for fspec in [1-4].txt ; do
    stat -c %y ${fspec} >>${fspec}
done
```

Note I've used `stat -c %y` to get the modification time such as `2017-02-09 12:21:22.848349503 +0800` - I'm not sure what variant of `stat` you're using but mine doesn't have a `-s` option. You can still use your option, you just have to ensure it's done on *each* file in turn, probably something like (in the `for` loop above):

```
stat -s ${fspec} | grep -o "st_mtime=[0-9]*" | sed "s/st_mtime=//g" >>${fspec}
```

Comment: The seconds option is given by `%Y` (in GNU stat). The apple version of stat has a `fmt` with `S` that use a `strftime` format (I assume that the %s could be used with it).

Comment: Hmmm... Do you live in China? That's the [time zone that match +0800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:00).

Comment: @sorontar: as does a sizable portion of Borneo, the Phillipines, the ROC and Western Australia (where I *actually* live). Though, of course, I'm considering applying for Chinese citizenship, if only to annoy the lunatic currently in charge of the US executive branch :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can not redirect the output to several files as in `> $files`.

To process several files you need something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./[0-4].txt ; do
    # get file modified time (in seconds)
    thedate="$(stat --printf='%Y\n' "$f")"   
    echo "$thedate" >> "$f"  
done
```

If you want a human readable time format change `%Y` by `%y`:

```
thedate="$(stat --printf='%y\n' "$f")"
```